# Datatable with fixed column missalinged

Tags: javascript, html, css, datatables

I am having an odd issue using DataTables with fixedColumn. Everything works fine but there is an space between the header and the list of rows that is displayed every-time I scroll the table horizontally.

[Datatable issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3uZX.png)

However, I can scroll all fixed rows and the table looks fine. (Try this by clicking on any row into the first column and press arrows up and down)

[DataTable after scrolling the fixedColumn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9QDC8.png)

Does anyone knows how to avoid this annoying issue? I appreciate any suggestion. 
Here the code and libraries I am using.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#MyTable').DataTable({
    paging: false,
    info: false,
    scrollX: true,
    fixedColumns: {
      leftColumns: 1
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- Data Table-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedcolumns/3.2.4/css/fixedColumns.dataTables.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedcolumns/3.2.4/js/dataTables.fixedColumns.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedheader/3.1.3/css/fixedHeader.dataTables.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedheader/3.1.3/js/dataTables.fixedHeader.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.4.0/Chart.min.js"></script>

<table class="table table-bordered text-center" id="MyTable" style="width: 100%;">
  <thead style="background-color: black; color: white;">
    <tr>
      <th style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: center;">Fixed</th>
      <th style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: center;">X</th>
      <th style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: center;">Y</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="success">
      <td>row 1</td>
      <td>193.38867</td>
      <td>150.45493</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="danger">
      <td>row 2</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="danger">
      <td>row 3</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="danger">
      <td>row 4</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="success">
      <td>row 5</td>
      <td>578.30164</td>
      <td>544.329</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="success">
      <td>row 6</td>
      <td>934.5156</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="danger">
      <td>row 7</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Try replacing `fixedColumns.dataTables.min.css` with `fixedColumns.bootstrap.min.css`.  This example shows the CSS and JS files needed for FixedColumns and BS3: https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedcolumns/examples/styling/bootstrap.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `fixedColumns.bootstrap.min.css` instead of `fixedColumns.dataTables.min.css`

See [official example](https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedcolumns/examples/styling/bootstrap.html) for more information.

See updated example below.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#MyTable').DataTable({
    paging: false,
    info: false,
    scrollX: true,
    fixedColumns: {
      leftColumns: 1
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.table-style1 thead th {
   background-color: black;
   color: white;
   vertical-align: middle; 
   text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- Data Table-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedcolumns/3.2.4/css/fixedColumns.bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedcolumns/3.2.4/js/dataTables.fixedColumns.min.js"></script>

<table class="table table-bordered text-center table-style1" id="MyTable" style="width: 100%;">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Fixed</th>
      <th>X</th>
      <th>Y</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="success">
      <td>row 1</td>
      <td>193.38867</td>
      <td>150.45493</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="danger">
      <td>row 2</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="danger">
      <td>row 3</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="danger">
      <td>row 4</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="success">
      <td>row 5</td>
      <td>578.30164</td>
      <td>544.329</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="success">
      <td>row 6</td>
      <td>934.5156</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="danger">
      <td>row 7</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! This works perfect to align rows and avoid the issue. But as you can see, now the fixed row loses their styles. Any idea!!

Comment: @OswaldoRubio, updated the code. Use CSS instead of applying the style directly to the `thead` and `th` elements.

Answer (score 1):

You are using too much css files fo `dataTables` which are conflicting with each other.

Just use `dataTables.bootstrap.min.css`

***Stack Snippet***

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var table = $('#MyTable').DataTable({
    scrollY: "300px",
    scrollX: true,
    scrollCollapse: true,
    paging: false,
    fixedColumns: {
      leftColumns: 1,
      rightColumns: 1
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedcolumns/3.2.4/css/fixedColumns.dataTables.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.4.0/Chart.min.js"></script>

<table class="table table-bordered text-center" id="MyTable" style="width: 100%;">
  <thead style="background-color: black; color: white;">
    <tr>
      <th style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: center;">Fixed</th>
      <th style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: center;">X</th>
      <th style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: center;">Y</th>
      <th style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: center;">Z</th>
      <th style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: center;">Z</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="success">
      <td>row 1</td>
      <td>193.38867</td>
      <td>150.45493</td>
      <td>150.45493</td>
      <td>150.45493</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="danger">
      <td>row 2</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="danger">
      <td>row 3</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="danger">
      <td>row 4</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="success">
      <td>row 5</td>
      <td>578.30164</td>
      <td>544.329</td>
      <td>544.329</td>
      <td>544.329</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="success">
      <td>row 6</td>
      <td>934.5156</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="danger">
      <td>row 7</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```